# select2-How to limit the max selection to one and prevent the user to enter more text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, limits

I have to limit the max selection in select 2 to one.
I familiar with the option `maximumSelectionSize: 1`, but this option enable the user to enter text to the input/selcect-2 container, and also provide a message with "You can only select  1 item", and I don't need this message, and the user shouldn't be able to enter more text to the input after selected.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @ D4V1D- I tried maximumSelectionSize: 1...

Answer (score 1):

Select2's option is default to limit the selection by 1. You don't need to use `maximumSelectionSize` option. Just call `$(".select2").select2();`.
See example [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: @shess- I use version 3.5.2 , and if I don't use maximumSelectionSize I can select multiple selections.

Comment: @shess- I noticed that I put multiple:true by mistake. I removed it but then all my css is changed:(